# How can a native token be removed/de-registered from Cardano token registry

Tags: cardano-cli

We have minted and registered a native token on Cardano. Now we want to burn it, because of change of policy and remove it from the registry.

After burning the tokens how should I de-register, so that it does not appear in cardanoscan any more?

Comment: One solution, i can think of is this. I would remove the entry that was created during token registration in the repository:https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry from the mapping/ directory. Would this remove the entry entirely from the registry ?

Comment: No, this will not work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions on how to do it within the Cardano Registry documentation
(https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/token-registry/How-do-I-delete-my-entry-from-the-registry%3F)

These are:

> Removing an entry from the registry is an ad-hoc process. If this was
> allowed without verification, anyone could delete anyone's metadata.
> The verification process is therefore identical to updating an entry,
> with the additional step of updating the value of the 'name' and
> 'description' fields to 'VOID' and explicitly mentioning in the title
> of your Pull Request that you would like the entry deleted.
>
> If the Pull Request passes validation (meaning you have signed the
> submission with the required key/s), the maintainers of the registry
> will delete your entry.
>
> Steps Update your entry by updating the value of the 'name' and
> 'description' fields to 'VOID'. Submit a pull request. Make sure to
> indicate in the title of your Pull Request that you would like the
> entry deleted.

Comment: Quality quoting, well done.